# Is It posible to Port Windows Forms apps to WPF Converting it's Designer.cs files to XAML files?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls, windows-forms-designer

Good day, I want to port my Windows Forms App to WPF, I have been investigating and I know that it's almost impossible to port it because of the designer.cs files of Winforms and WPF uses .XAML, but, [this web page](https://www.win2wpf.com)converts your designer files to XAML, so, it is still possible?

Comment: Even if it "works", I doubt it would be desirable. If you are doing WPF you will want to follow an MVVM paradigm and it is highly unlikely the WinForm will be designed such a way as to do the translation.

Comment: Don't go this path.. just don't. You'll regret it. It is not compatible. Only thing in common is that it is desktop tech. And .Net :-)

Comment: You may have some success hosting WinForms controls in WPF using WindowsFormsHost (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost?view=netframework-4.7.1), but, as others said, you really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can't port YourForm.Designer.cs because the `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Windows.Controls` are different classes. But there's still a way. Add the namespace of Windows Forms to XAML code. Then, use a WindowsFormsHost. You may add them only with WindowsFormsHost. Then, just copy your methods to C# code of WPF application.

Note: Do not forget to name your controls in WindowsFormsHost correctly.
Note 2: You must check your code after that operations. Because something may need to change.